# react doesn't render latest value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect, react-dom

For the initial render, I have object `date`, which is an empty array. I then try to get data from an influxDB, but the get result isn't reflected by React with a re-render. The get function is calling in `useEffect` (you can see this in screenshots). I use typescript, and to avoid getting an error on the initial load (that data is an empty array of objects and it doesn't have a value property) I use the typescript syntax, but it still doesn't display the correct value. It doesn't display anything at all.

What could be the problem? In the last photo, we can see another way to display data without a question mark from typescript, but it doesn't work correctly either, even if the length of the array is greater than 0, it still doesn't display `data[0].value`.

**Initial data**:
[image: initial data]

**Data after DB get**:
[image: data when function return finally results]

**Get the first element in array**:
[image: get the value of the first object in array]

**Browser result** (before ':' we should see `data[0].value`):
[image: results in the browser]

**Alternate way** (when data isn't empty we should see the value of the first object in array):
[image: another way]

I also show we code

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { FluxTableMetaData } from '@influxdata/influxdb-client';

const { InfluxDB } = require('@influxdata/influxdb-client');

export const App = () => {
  debugger
  const authData = {
    token: 'Emyw1rqUDthYRLpmmBc6O1_yt9rGTT57O50zoKiXUoScAjL6G-MgUN6G_U9THilr86BfIPHMYt6_KSDNHhc9Jg==',
    org: 'testOrg',
    bucket: 'test-bucket',
  };

  const client = new InfluxDB({
    url: 'http://localhost:8086',
    token: authData.token,
  });

  const queryApi = client.getQueryApi(authData.org);
  const query = `from(bucket: "${authData.bucket}") |> range(start: -1d)`;

  const data: any[] = [];
  React.useEffect(() => {
    queryApi.queryRows(query, {
      next(row: string[], tableMeta: FluxTableMetaData) {
        debugger;
        const o = tableMeta.toObject(row);
        const item = {
          time: o._time,
          measurement: o._measurement,
          field: o._field,
          value: o._value,
        };
        return data.push(item);
      },
      error(error: Error) {
        return error;
      },
      complete() {
        console.log(data)
        return data;
      },

    })
  },[]);

  debugger;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{data.length !== data[0].value}:</div>
      <div>hello</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

another way:

```
<div>
  <div>{data[0]?.value}:</div>
  <div>hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in your code is, You have defined data as a `const` variable, and not as a `state`. Thus, in `useEffect`, even if your `data` gets changed, it will not reflect on `data[0].value` as it is a const variable and react doesn't render updated values of variables. It updates/renders only if it's a state.

In short, Convert your `const` data to be a `state`and use `setState` like below for your code to work!

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
...
setData([...data , item]);
```

Comment: Thank you! It's helped me, but something i changed.
    on every item: `return data.push(item)`
 when "loop finished": `return setData(data))`    Тhis is another simple error i got)))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the React States for that in the following way

```
var [nameOfVariableWhichWillChange, changeFunction] = React.useState("");
```

now whenever whichever function wants to change the value of that function just use `changeFunction(newValueOfVariable)`
the plus point of using React state is wherever you might have used that variable on change of That variable each instance will change on its own...
Do let me know does that solve your problem, or you need something else

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's helped me, but something i changed. on every item: `return data.push(item)` when "loop finished": `return setData(data)` Тhis is another simple error i got)))

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't re-render the webpage even if the data has changed. You need to store your data inside a `React.useState` and call `setState` to trigger a re-render.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

React.useEffect(() => {
  ...
  next(row: string[], tableMeta: FluxTableMetaData) {
    ...
    setData([...data, item])
  },
...
```

Read about `useState` here for more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Thank you for your help and link! It's helped me, but something i changed. on every item: `return data.push(item)` when "loop finished": `return setData(data)` Тhis is another simple error i got)))